# Flutter : Closure call with mismatched arguments: function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I have created below builder method to build my widget dynamically :

```
    Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description,
      var currentValue, Function updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: updateValue,
    );
  }
```

You can see above **updateValue**

Calling it as below :

```
 _buildSwitchListTile(
              'Gluten-free',
              'Only include gluten-free meals.',
              _glutenFree,
              (newValue) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _glutenFree = newValue;
                  },
                );
              },
            )
```

Issue is I am getting Compile time error (red mark) near **updateValue** in _buildSwitchListTile method.

It's Saying :

> The argument type 'Function' can't be assign to the parameter type
> 'void Function (bool)?'.

**That's Issue no.1**

**Below is the Runtime issue** :
If I add (paranthesis) as updateValue() then error is gone but am getting runtime error as below :

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_FiltersScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>'
    Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => Null
    Tried calling: _FiltersScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>()
    Found: _FiltersScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>(dynamic) => Null
```

Below is the pic for reference :

[image]

What will be the possible solution I should have? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change callback function like `unction(bool)? updateValue` or `unction(bool)? updateValue` because the `onChanged` is `void Function(T value);`

```dart
 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description,
      var currentValue, Function(bool) updateValue) {
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit about it ? Much appreciated.

Comment: `SwitchListTile` onchange returns a bool value, means true/false based on this widget state. So in order to satisfy the `onChanged` you need to provide same type of parameters. You can check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile/onChanged.html)